# How to fire Timer only once for specific values

Tags: vb.net

Since there aren't really good apps for instant crypt price alerts, I'm doing it by myself.
I'm struggling when comes to send the alert to my phone because I want the timer to fire just once for every value I choose.
I'm sending the alerts through Pushbullet API to my phone and I don't want to flood it.

I'm parsing the "price" through an online API by timer1 in real-time. Everything works perfectly, but the timer2. Obviously timer 1 is ticking every 5 seconds to check if the price is above the value I chosen, but then if the price rises above that chosen value then it's sending the alert through PushBullet every time it ticks. How can I let the timer1 check if the price is above the values and if yes tick just one?
The closest idea I got is :

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
       If CInt(price) > 0.05060 Then
           timer2.start
       ElseIf CInt(price) > 0.05080 Then
            timer2.start
        ElseIf CInt(price) < 0.04960 Then
            timer2.start
       End If
  
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
       Pushbullet("Price above 0.05060") 
       '[....]
       '[....]
       Timer2.Stop()
   End Sub
```

Obviously, It's important not to stop timer1, but instead timer2. But how can I manage this? I'm quite stuck on it. Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: A simple method would be to use a variable, declared within your class, to hold the last "price" value that was checked.  Then you can compare the current price that you've retrieved with the last price that was alerted.  If the current price would trigger the same alert (ie. fall within the same "if" condition) as the last price, then there's no need to do the timer2.start within the "if" condition.  Only when the current price matches a different "if" condition than the last price would it be necessary for an alert to occur

Comment: Why do you have `CInt` in that code? How are you going to get fine-grained comparisons like you're trying to there when `CInt` cannot produce a value between 1 and 0?

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Private previousPrice As Double

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If (price > 0.05060 AndAlso previousPrice <= 0.05060) OrElse
       (price > 0.05080 AndAlso previousPrice <= 0.05080) OrElse
       (price < 0.04960 AndAlso previousPrice >= 0.04960)
        timer2.Start()
    End If

    previousPrice = price
```

I've used type `Double` there because you did in your code but those values really ought to be type `Decimal`.

You might also consider not hard-coding those values so that they can be changed easily without recompiling, e.g.

```vb
Private upperThresholds As New List(Of Double) From {0.05060, 0.05080}
Private lowerThresholds As New List(Of Double) From {0.04960}
Private previousPrice As Double

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If upperThresholds.Any(Function(threshold) price > threshold AndAlso previousPrice <= threshold) OrElse
       lowerThresholds.Any(Function(threshold) price < threshold AndAlso previousPrice >= threshold)
        timer2.Start()
    End If

    previousPrice = price
```

Now you can add, edit and remove values in those lists as required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The only thing I'm not understanding now is how can I tell to timer2 that the price is above or below n?

Comment: Probably I wrong explained myself in the last comment. This is still part of my question as Timer 1 is doing half of the job. So, correct me if I'm doing or saying something wrong, as Im here to learn. Timer1 thanks to your code, is firing just after the price rises or goes below the values I chosen. Ok, then timer2 should send a push notification as I said with PushBullet API. My question is, how does timer2 knows if price raises or went below? I am not understanding this.

Comment: like:   `Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        Pushbullet( how does timer2 knows about what to send here? Price rises or went below x??)
        Timer2.Stop()
    End Sub`